# Obsolete potentiometer

Tags: potentiometer

[image]I am not a electrical engineer I am a rancher. I came across this site while searching for someone that could possibly repair a potentiometer. My problem is this.I have a cat 303 excavator incorporated in the Kawasaki joy stick is a potentiometer built by a company called Midori. This comes on a 1996 Caterpillar/Mitsubishi 303 mini excavator around 7500 lbs. The repair shop working on trying to solve this has been trying to fix the machine for the past several months with nothing but dead ends.The joystick and all components are now obsolete. I have been desperately trying to find a way to get this machine repaired.It all comes down to a single component. I really don’t want to have to scrap the machine it’s been a real life saver on my ranch. So I said that to say this is there some out there that could repair the potentiometer. I would gladly pay for the work and would provide any information that I have. The fella has described in detail the problem and his specific diagnostic. He is very gifted at his trade and has identified the requirements of the potentiometer.If anyone out there could help with this challenge it would bring a old rancher great joy and maybe a few less trips to the Chiropractor.Please know I mean no disrespect to this forum by soliciting a repair service I am trying to get a extremely difficult situation dealt with.HELP!!!!
Sincerely
Rick

Comment: Questions on repair or recommendations for replacement parts are off topic for this site. You might search Digi-Key or Mouser for a similar part

Comment: If you can take a photo, it is possible to make this an "identify the part" question.

Comment: `identified the requirements of the potentiometer` ... what is the requirement? ... you talk about everything else, except about the potentiometer

Comment: As mentioned previously this question is off-topic for this site.  You might try posting on eevblog.com forums, you could possibly find help there.  Also posting a photo and as much technical info as possible might help identify the component or a replacement.

Comment: Unless a really unusual size/shape, the chances are good at finding *something* that will work.  They may have been custom-made at the time.  But we need some photos and specifications at least.  Ask the current repairperson if they have any specs for it or can measure it - linear or log taper, how many gangs, resistance, power handling capability, etc.

Comment: That letter you show gives you the potentiometer info: 16k single turn... Now go to supplier sites and find an equivalent.

Comment: Perhaps this might point you somewhere: https://www.jukebox-world.de/Elektrik/Potentiometer/Potentiometer-16-kOhm-5-kOhm.html

Comment: Sadly we have tried that but a lot of dead ends. The company Moldari is in Japan they have been very little help not sure why but I suspect trade agreements. That’s why I chose this site thought maybe someone here might be able to shed some light. Part of the problem has been this is a gray model excavator.